# Can I share sound file using facebook?

Tags: iphone, facebook

I want to share an audio file(mp3,wav) from IPhone application to facebook.

Anyone knows how do I do that ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Would suggest uploading the file to some service and sharing that link with the Facebook share URL (e.g. http://facebook.com/share.php?u=http://blablbla.com/file.mp3)

Shai.